# Increasing engine rpm when AC on

Tags: engine, ac, rpm, maruti, alto

I have **Maruti Alto LXI 2004** model.Now it has driven **96000 km**. When I drive on traffic with AC,the engine rpm increase as unusually. And also engine power is go down.... what can I do for that??

Comment: I completely agree with @SolarMike's answer, I'd just add if you are noticing a loss of power that wasn't there before it's very unlikely to be related to the AC.

Comment: Install a turbo kit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the A/C is switched on the engine ecu increases the idle speed by a few hundred rpm to make sure the engine does not stall and keep a "smooth" idle. This is normal.

Also, the A/C system can demand some 10bhp or so during its operation - which is why some people will switch off the A/C when doing an overtake for example.

So, if you want the power back then minimize your use of A/C...

Comment: can I know this problem relate with condition of alternator and battery????

Comment: @RathnayakeArachchige How are you evaluating the condition of the alternator and battery? What readings have you recorded under what conditions?

Comment: I haven't any record about battery and alternator because, Im the 4th owner this vehicle. Odometer shows around 96000km. Im sure there was not any replacement of alternator or battery.....